# Azure automation - credentials delivered by Get-PSAutomationCredential don't work with Add-AzureAccount?

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-authentication

I'm modifying a gallery runbook that copies a live database to a test database on a schedule. It's failing at the first hurdle; authenticating and selecting the relevatn azure subscription

The runbook looks like this:

```
$Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'automationCredential'

Write-Output "UN: $($Cred.Username)"

Add-AzureAccount -Credential $Cred
```

I've used the portal credentials blade to create a credential named "automationCredential". For the username and password I supplied the username/pw that I log into the azure portal with. Note: this is NOT a school/work microsoft account, but a personal one

I can tell the call to Get-PSAutomationCredential is working out, because the `Write-Ouput` call shows the correct value

Add-AzureAccount however, delivers the following error:

```
Add-AzureAccount : unknown_user_type: Unknown User Type At
Set-DailyDatabaseRestore:22 char:22 CategoryInfo          :
CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureAccount], AadAuthenticationFailedException
FullyQualifiedErrorId :
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.AddAzureAccount
```

Any pointers how to get a working credential?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, it seems that your account is a Microsoft account(such as *@outlook.com, *@hotmail.com). Microsoft does not support non-interactive login. It is also unsafe for you to use your account to login your subscription directly. For a runbook, you could use the following codes to logon.

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}
```

In above code, you need use connection `AzureRunAsConnection`, it is created by Azure default, you could use it directly, you could check this connection, it includes your subscription information.
[image]

Also, you could create a new connection, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-connections).

Comment: @CaiusJard When you create a Azure automation runbook, it is create a service principal and used for connection. This is recommend by Azure. More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-create-runas-account).

Comment: Holy smokes, something in this endeavour that's actually worked out; thanks walter!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the resource manager version off the login cmdlet (Add-AzureRmAccount)?

Comment: Tat seems to get things a little further along; i now have it complaining about the next line "the subscription id abcdef1234-blahblah does not exist"

Comment: Are you using the RM version of this cmdlet also? (Select-AzureRmSubscription)