# Azure automation: Authentication succeeds but no subscriptions are returned, works in local powershell though

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-authentication

Having a problem with creating an azure automation runbook that will copy a database on demand; I've created a credential and stored the u/p of the account I use to log into the portal in it. Password was written in notepad and pasted in to ensure correct.

```
$Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'automationCredential'

Write-Output "UN: $($Cred.Username)"
Write-Output "PW: $($Cred.Password.Length)"

Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Cred

Write-Output "Deleting the old $TargetDatabaseName"

Remove-AzureRMSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "Default-SQL-NorthEurope" -ServerName $SourceServerName -DatabaseName $TargetDatabaseName -Force

Write-Output "Creating new $TargetDatabaseName with data at time $PointInTime"

New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy `
    -CopyDatabaseName $TargetDatabaseName `
    -DatabaseName $SourceDatabaseName `
    -ResourceGroupName "Default-SQL-NorthEurope" `
    -ServerName $SourceServerName
```

The debug prints seem to indicate the credentials are correct, but when the add-azurermaccount is carried out, it seems to log in but no subscriptions are returned

Soon after the call to remove the old test db fails with:

> Remove-AzureRMSqlDatabase : No subscription found in the context.  Please ensure that the credentials you provided are 
>   authorized to access an Azure subscription, then run Login-AzureRMAccount to login.

If I do the actions in the command line powershell (the only difference being I call login without parameters; it prompts for creds) then things work out just fine

I found some resources that indicate if the creds are wrong, it authenticates but returns no subscriptions - i've double checked the creds tho and they're accurate

Comment: what azurerm version are you using?

Comment: No idea; how do I find it out? I just write this code into portal.azure.com's editor then go to the test pane, add arguments and run it

Answer (score 2):

In Azure, Microsoft account does **not** support **non-interactive** login.
If you want to use script to login Azure in runbook, we can create a **service principal** to login Azure.

We can use powershell to create Azure service principal, more information about service principal, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal).

---

We can use service principal to login Azure powershell, like this:

```
$subscriptionId="5384xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxe29axxxx"
$tenantid="1fcf418e-66ed-4c99-9449-d8e18bf8737a"
$appid="1498b171-e1ca-451f-9d7a-8ef56a178b89" 
$password="7db814b1-xxxx-4654-xxxx-1d210cb546f9"
$userPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$userCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $clientid, $userPassword
Add-AzureRmAccount -TenantId $tenantid -ServicePrincipal -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -Credential $userCredential
```

[image][image]

About create [service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-kubernetes-service-principal), we can use CLI 2.0 to create it, like this:

```
az login

az account set --subscription "mySubscriptionID"

az group create -n "myResourceGroupName" -l "westus"

az ad sp create-for-rbac --role="Contributor" --scopes="/subscriptions/mySubscriptionID/resourceGroups/myResourceGroupName"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jason. Could you feed that back to whatever team is responsible for maintaining this stuff, that an error message like "Using a Microsoft Account with Azure does not support non-interactive login. Create a Service Principal instead", would be more helpful than returning an object that looks like auth succeeded, but is devoid of any useful purpose?

Comment: @CaiusJard thanks for your feedback. Have you try to use service principal to login Azure, does this work now?

Comment: I've created a service principal, but there's clearly still a part of the process missing, because I now see `Add-AzureRmAccount : AADSTS70001: Application with identifier 'serviceproviders' was not found in the directory 
<directory id here>
Trace ID: 7dfa8201-ba29-4ad8-98fb-8aba3f172900`.

Comment: Walter-MSFT has given some good advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015557, that enabled me to get a login that worked out

Comment: @CaiusJard yes, that is a easy way to login azure, also we can use powershell to login it, I have update my answer, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant b0b9849f-09b0-4cf8-b157-4662860ccb4c
```