# Unable to sign in to azure subscription through Azure Automation

Tags: azure, automation, azure-powershell

I want to execute a runbook from subscription A which will create a storage a/c on subscription B. I provided the (Username/Password) of subscription B in credential asset.

Firstly, please let me know is it possible to do that ?

When i try to run the below code, it gives an error "Unable to acquire token for tenant 'Common' " when i run Get-AzureRmSubscription

```
$CredentialAssetName = "login";
$Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name $CredentialAssetName
if(!$Cred) {
Throw "Could not find an Automation Credential Asset named 
'${CredentialAssetName}'. Make sure you have created one in this Automation 
 Account."
 }
 add-azurermaccount -credential $Cred 
 login-AzureRMAccount -Credential $Cred

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName 'Free Trial'
get-azurermsubscription
```

Comment: It is possible to create a storage account in another subscription with Azure runbook,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unable to acquire token for tenant 'Common'

It just a WARNING, that will not affect your script.

> please let me know is it possible to do that?

Yes, it is possible, we can use Azure runbook to login subscription B, and use PowerShell to create an Azure storage account in that subscription.

Runbook just like PowerShell, when we use subscription B to log in, the script will work on subscription B.

If subscription B is a Microsoft account, we can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019621/azure-automation-authentication-succeeds-but-no-subscriptions-are-returned-wor/45023742#45023742) to login Azure runbook. (Microsoft account does **not** support non-interactive login.)

Comment: 1)Microsoft Account does not support non-interactive login, so we should create a SP,  if your account support non-interactive login, we can use that account and password to login2)appid is one output of SP, 3) yes, create from subscription B

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I want to get some clarity on few points for better understanding. (1) What is the need to create a service principal, providing global admin credential of subscription B wont work ? (2) What is the appID variable in the script ? (3) I need to execute CLI commands to create service principal from subscription B..correct ?